# Fetching HTTP GET variables in Python

Tags: python, http, get

I'm trying to set up a HTTP server in a Python script. So far I got the server it self to work, with a code similar to the below, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617615/slow-python-http-server-on-localhost).

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("Just received a GET request")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write('Hello world')

        return

    def log_request(self, code=None, size=None):
        print('Request')

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        print('Message')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 80), MyHandler)
        print('Started http server')
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C received, shutting down server')
        server.socket.close()
```

However, I need to get variables from the GET request, so if `server.py?var1=hi` is requested, I need the Python code to put `var1` into a Python variable and process it (like print it). How would I go about this? Might be a simple question to you Python pros, but this Python beginner doesn't know what to do! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`urlparse.parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urllib%20parse%20parse_qs#urlparse.parse_qs)

```
print urlparse.parse_qs(os.environ['QUERY_STRING'])
```

Or if you care about order or duplicates, [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urllib%20parse%20parse_qs#urlparse.parse_qsl).

[**Import in Python 3:**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Comment: I did come across that, but I'm not sure how to integrate this... Could you give me a short example?

Comment: `urlparse.parse_qs()` returns a dictionary. Use it as you would any other dictionary in Python.

Comment: Just checked this answer, and I can't find where BaseHTTPServer sets environment variables. CGIHTTPServer does.

Answer (score 9):

Import `urlparse` and do:

```
def do_GET(self):
    qs = {}
    path = self.path
    if '?' in path:
        path, tmp = path.split('?', 1)
        qs = urlparse.parse_qs(tmp)
    print path, qs
```

Comment: One can also apply `parse_qs` to `urlparse(self.path).query` instead of splitting *path* manually.