# How to link a discord embed to a plain text file in http.server

Tags: python

I've been struggling with this a lot
I'm trying to make a website where you could run Lua by a link
It goes like "http://localhost:5000/Lua/return%20'Hello World!'"
And I want to make it so it returns a response for Discord too

For example:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)

        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/txt")
        self.end_headers()
        # Sending a discord header?

        self.wfile.write(
            b'Something'
        )

Server = HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8000), RequestHandler)
Server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: what is the problem? What did you try? Did you get error message? Always show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Frankly, I would rather use `flask` instead of `http.server`

Comment: [Processing HTTP GET input parameter on server side in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928730/processing-http-get-input-parameter-on-server-side-in-python)

Comment: it may need to use `self.path` to get url. Next it will need to check if it has `/Lua/code` and split to get code after `/Lua/`. Next it will need to use `subprocess.run()` to run external program like `lua`.

Comment: No that is not the problem i made the Lua running system, the problem is making an embed for Discord

Comment: were do you have code for discord? What module do you use to create discord bot?

Comment: Just check this image out:https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1136231142492737597/1177226186754113636/image.png?ex=6571bc52&is=655f4752&hm=9ce4cac40780a0e8ed3c8554d5b9ad313b028f2da3ea28ca8526f0aa5d638420&