# Sending and parsing an HTTP POST request with Python

Tags: python, post, cgi, python-requests, httpserver

Could someone tell me what is going wrong with this simple server setup? It's based on the same code as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946684/java-post-to-python-http-server-not-working) and possibly a similar issue - but I need a POST request rather than a GET which was the eventual resolution in the other question? The problem is that `self.args` is empty when I had expected `{'verify': 'true'}`.

Here's my POST request:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
data = {'verify': 'true'}
response = requests.post(url, params=data)

print response.text
```

And the handler which is running on localhost:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.query_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
        self.args = dict(cgi.parse_qsl(self.query_string))
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Content-type: text/html<BR><BR>");
        self.wfile.write("<HTML>POST OK.<BR><BR>");

def main():
    server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The handler is outputting `Jamie-PC - - [15/Jul/2013 12:40:34] "POST /?verify=true HTTP/1.1" 200 -` in case that helps.

Comment: POST requests (typically) do not use the query string for passing around parameters. Instead, they're passed along inside the request's body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: BaseHTTPRequestHandler post variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233218/python-basehttprequesthandler-post-variables)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see that duplicate - I'll try and get that working.

Comment: The accepted answer on that suggested duplicate almost worked for me. I found I need to do `Request().prepare()` first which seems to be setting the `content-length` header which is otherwise left blank.

Comment: @JamieBull Glad that worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is to use `data` instead of `params`as in:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/'
data = {'verify': 'true'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print response.text
```

This sets all the other necessary headers, like content-length.