# Troubles with http server on linux

Tags: python, performance, http

I have such problem. I have local http server (BottlePy or Django), and when i use http:// localhost/ or http:// 127.0.0.1/ - it loads immediately. But when i use my local ip (192.168.1.100), it loads very long time (some minutes). What could be the problem?

Server works on Ubuntu 11.

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at 
[Slow Python HTTP server on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617615/slow-python-http-server-on-localhost)
similar issues has been resolved there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have problems with DNS. can you check this idea running `host 192.168.1.100` on the host? Please also check that other DNS queries being quickly processed. 
Check `/etc/hosts` file for a quick-and-dirty solution.